# Data privacy and Access Modifiers java

Tags: java, encapsulation, access-modifiers

I am currently in the middle of a project, and I have a slight dilemma. Say I have a class called A. In class A, there is a private nested class called B. Then I created another class called C which inherits A. Do I need to make B protected so that C can access it? or is there another way to keep B private and still let C access that class.

In general, is it better to use protected or use private and create getters and setters?
Which one is better for variable / method privacy>

Comment: the protected, public, private attributes are not meant for data privacy. Are meant for method privacy. There's no relation at all between method privacy and data privacy in the way you refer.

Comment: I actually meant variable privacy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No , that’s why private is for .
You don’t want even class that inherit from you are able to access to it.

You can have a protected method which always return a new instance of B or return singleton of B, if you really need to access from your class child.

And for your last question , are you asking about variable inside classes?

Comment: yes I meant variable and method privacy

Comment: For variable, it's better to have getter and setter, but only with required variables, especially setter.  For method, i think it all depends on your needs. If your class gonna inherit by many child classes and they have some own behavior, is good to have your method as public or protected, which enable your  child classes to override if they need.  Private method when you do not want anyone able to change it and modify it and call it outside of your class.